# How can I use the Ord::max function?

Tags: compiler-errors, rust

In this trivial program, I attempt to call `i32.max(i32)`:

```
fn main() {
    let a: i32 = 0;
    let b: i32 = 1;
    let c: i32 = a.max(b);  // <-- Error here
    println!("{}", c);
}
```

But I get a cryptic compile-time error:

```
error: no method named `max` found for type `i32` in the current scope
 --> prog.rs:4:17
  |
4 |     let c: i32 = a.max(b);
  |                    ^^^
  |
  = note: the method `max` exists but the following
    trait bounds were not satisfied: `i32 : std::iter::Iterator`
```

Why does this happen? I'm using Rust 1.17.0.

How can I use the [`max()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.Ord.html#method.max) (or [`min()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.Ord.html#method.min)) function?

The example works if I use a floating point value:

```
let a: f32 = 0.0;
let b: f32 = 1.0;
let c: f32 = a.max(b);
```

This makes things more mysterious.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It works fine with a more recent compiler.  You can see this by [trying it on the playpen](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=b06421e6084faedee6a57a8bb88b2089&version=stable).

The problem is that you're trying to call a method *that doesn't exist*.  At least, not in the version of Rust you're using.  The [documentation for `Ord::max`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.Ord.html#method.max) notes that it was introduced in Rust version 1.21.0.

What you want is to use [`cmp::max`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.17.0/std/cmp/fn.max.html), which is a function, *not a method*.  Thus, you call it like so:

```
use std::cmp;
let c = cmp::max(a, b);
```

As for why it works for `f32`, the answer to that can be found by checking the documentation: [a search for `max`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.17.0/std/index.html?search=max) reveals that `f32` and `f64` have their own versions of a `max` method.  And *that's* because both `cmp::max` and `Ord::max` only work on types that have a total ordering.  Floats are *not* totally ordered due to the existence of NaN, so they cannot use either of those.

Comment: That was a dumb oversight I made! I read the version that APIs are introduced to Java and Python. For Rust, I assumed that integer min/max are so basic that they should have been implemented since the beginning of time. I didn't think to check the API version at all here.

Comment: Note that you can browse the docs for any version of the language, either by opening the docs that ship with the compiler, or by adding the version number to the URL (check the URL I used for `cmp::max`).

Comment: @Nayuki *I assumed that integer min/max are so basic that they should have been implemented since the beginning of time* — [They were](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/fn.max.html).

Answer (score -2):

If you want to compare numbers, you'd do it like this:

```
use std::cmp;

fn main() {
    let a: i32 = 0;
    let b: i32 = 1;
    let c: i32 = cmp::max(a, b);
    println!("{}", c);
}
```

Comment: I mean it's a solution, but doesn't explain much

Comment: Yeah, that's on me ~ should have noticed earlier that you were asking not just for a working code example :).